# how to save xml file from html page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, xml

I have requirement to save an XML document which is displayed in a HTML page.

The scenario is like this: I am sending search request to the server and  in return I am getting  xml file but displayed in html page. What I want is to save client-side the xml file displayed inside the html form, using javascript, asp.net (C#).

Please see this link (server return file like this)
http://www.w3schools.com/dom/books.xml

Comment: Please confirm you need to save XML file on client side - where client is accessing your application from browser. It is not recommended to depend on file system access from within browser. Browser environment is supposed to be sandbox, protecting the OS resources from potential threats. Depending upon security level, browsers might not allow saving of file through javascript.

Comment: If I get you right, the xml content is inside a <form> element, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the stream from your request into a xmldoc.
Should be really straight forward.

Have a look here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.save(v=vs.100).aspx

Also, here there is a microsoft article about it:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307643

Answer (score 0):

The sent file should have a HTTP header indicating it's meant to be saved, not shown.
Do it this way:

```
context.Response.ContentType = "application/force-download";
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are writing a client app to consume this file

```
using System.Net;
new WebClient().DownloadFile("http://www.w3schools.com/dom/books.xml", @"c:\books.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

As Rutesh said you can't go with javascript. Save it on the server with C#.NET and then access it from server. Secondly, the page you are talking about is not an html page its an xml file. I hope you know how to build an asp.net page, if yes then use this:

```
    XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
    xdoc.Load("http://www.w3schools.com/dom/books.xml");
    xdoc.Save("myfilename.xml");
```

Happy coding!

Comment: yes Ashwin singh i know how to build asp.net page and the page i am talking about is xml [by viewing source] but just to elaborate i have used html page .

Answer (score 0):

```
sourceResponse.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"; 
byte[] responseContent = "XML File content"
sourceResponse.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}.xml", "yourFileName"));
sourceResponse.BinaryWrite(responseContent);
sourceResponse.End();
```

Comment: Can you give the OP a little more context on where this should go?